# NodeJS vs Java in financial application development

Tags: java, node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I have searched quite a few financial applications and the majority of them are developed using *Java* or mainly *Java*.

I am working on a blockchain fintech application using *Hyperledger fabric*. Since *Hyperledger fabric* provides a Client SDK for both *Java* and *NodeJS*, I am more inclined toward using *NodeJS* because first of all I am comfortable with *NodeJS* and secondly *Hyperledger Fabric Client SDK* for *Nodejs* is more mature than its implementation for *Java*.

But as most of the fin-tech applications are developed using Java. I want to know if:

Are there some special reasons behind using *Java* for fin-tech applications ?

Is it a good idea to use *NodeJS* for this project ?

Comment: “More mature”?  You appear to be comparing a blockchain library with… Java SE, which does not have a blockchain library.  That comparison makes little sense.  I would compare Hyperledger Fabric with some blockchain libraries for Java before making a decision.

Comment: I am asking for comparison of JAVA and Hyperledger fabric. I want to know if there is any special reason that mostly fin-tech application uses JAVA? Is it good idea to implement a fin-tech application in NodeJS? What are the security risks?

Comment: check this link https://rclayton.silvrback.com/speaking-intelligently-about-java-vs-node-performance

Comment: It’s off topic to hyperledger fabric please remove hyperledger fabric tag

Comment: The financial sector moves slowly. Currently you could make a lot of money by porting old COBOL code to Java. NodeJS is a recent invention compared to a quarter of a century of Java, and it's a risk to do things differently than others are doing. "If it works, don't fix it".

Answer (score 0):

*Java* is more robust and have higher performance than *NodeJS*. However both can be used for implementing almost any application, it's just a matter of preference by developers/companies about which technology stack they will choose according to their expertise and the project/client requirements.

Check this link for more performance wise comparison:
https://rclayton.silvrback.com/speaking-intelligently-about-java-vs-node-performance